# Do Stack() will be collect by garbage collector .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, garbage-collection, stack

In `myFunction()`, I define a stack like : `Stack myStack = new Stack()`. Will `myStack` be collected by GC or not if `myFunction()` run many times on server?  If not please suggest me a way to use something like stack in asp.Net or the way better to increase performance. I'm still learning about asp.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a variable is declared locally in a method and no references to it exist outside of the scope of the method, then at the end of the method, the reference held by the local variable will no longer exist. The (previously) referenced object no longer has any references and therefore becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: myStack is inside a class which I use as custom validator in my model. So it totally be collected by GC when model have been checked valid already, am I right?

Comment: @Nampd Is it a local variable in a method, or a field or a property of a class?

Comment: It's a local variable @spender

Comment: So you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your `myStack` variable inside of the scope of your `myFunction()` call, it will not be garbage collected until the end of the `myFunction()` call. For example:

```
public void myFunction()
{
    Stack myStack = new Stack();
    //do stuff with myStack
}
```

In this situation, if you call `myFunction()`, your `myStack` variable will be garbage collected once your `myFunction()` call is over. However, if you are accessing the `myStack` variable inside of the `myFunction()` method (from some other scope), it won't be garbage collected at the end of the `myFunction()` call because there is (likely) another reference to it.